# I am trying to search URL for a string

Tags: jquery, url, window.location

I am looking to use jquery to search for a certain string that gets tagged onto the end of the page url after a user submits a form.

The url looks like

```
https://somerandomsite.com/?page_id=1423#wpcf7-f1448-p1423-o1
```

The only part of the string that stays consistent is the "wpcf7" so I am looking to target that with jquery and if it finds it run some code. Maybe use window.location.pathname somehow.

Any help would be much appreciated.

============================================

I got it everyone, thanks for your help. I don't think I was very clear in explaining the problem so I apologize.

```
if(document.location.hash.substr(1,5) === 'wpcf7'){
$('#formalert').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: ive tried document.location.pathname.match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part is called the hash and is referenced as:

```
location.hash
```

This includes the `#` character itself, so you have to skip that:

```
location.hash.substr(1)
```

To get the first part behind it:

```
location.hash.substr(1).split('-')[0]
```

**Update**

The final condition would be this:

```
if (document.location.hash.substr(1).split('-')[0] === 'wpcf7') {
    // do whatever
}
```

Comment: i still need to find the string wpcf7 after the hash, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Okay I looked up documentation on .split() so I understand what youre doing now.  I am still confused as to how I can run an even based on that string using your code. I've updated my question with how I think I can run it.

Comment: @user1324700 I see, you want to run code as soon as the hash changes right? I've updated that in my answer

Comment: I think this is becoming more complicated than it needs to be, after form is submitted it just appends an id to the end of the url, I just want to parse the url for the beginning of the string (wpfc7). Forget the hash tag all together unless what youre describing is required.

Comment: @user1324700 well, you said you wanted to run an event ... that wasn't very clear then ... in any case, simply an `if (location.hash.substr .... etc) { ... }` would do, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) for this:

```
str.search('wpcf7')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var urlPart = location.hash.substr(1);    // Retrieve part after dash #
var pages = urlPart.split('-'); // Split this part on "-"

var myInterstingPart = page[0]; // Get the first.
```

No?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
if (window.location.hash.indexOf("wpcf7") != -1) {
   alert('window contains wpcf7');
}
```